# AWS Windows EC2 is in private subnet but website in IIS needs to be accessible from a public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On AWS, I have VPC containing public and private subnet. Internet Gateway and Routing Tables are configured. I have configured Windows AWS EC2 instance in private subnet. Necessary IAM role, System Manager and Session Manager is configured and working. Security group allows HTTPS requests from anywhere to port 443. I have hosted website in IIS on port 443.
I want to access this website from any public IP through Public IPv4 DNS assigned by AWS. With above setup its not working.

Comment: Why did you put the EC2 instance in a private subnet?

Comment: It’s organisation level mandatory compliance

Comment: as per what's defined in security guidelines - Do not use default VPC and Start with one public subnet and at least a private one, and the EC2 instance should always go into private subnet

Comment: Is that a quote from your company's security guidelines? What does it say about granting public access to web servers?

Comment: Yes, quote is from from organization. Web server access - Route port 443 request Through the public subnet and from there into the private one.

Comment: Well, the only way to route it through the public subnet is to use a Load Balancer, or another EC2 instance that forwards the request (but your rules won't allow that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EC2 instance is in a **private network** which means that it is **not accessible from the Internet**. This is the explicit purpose of using a private subnet.

Your options are:

- Put the EC2 instance in a **public subnet**, or
- Put a **Load Balancer** in a public subnet (charges apply) and configure it to forward HTTP/S requests to the EC2 instance in the private subnet

Comment: Thanks. Does adding NAT to internet and then adding 0.0.0.0 to NAT entry in private subnet help? Or doing this is equal to having public subnet

Comment: No. NAT provides _outbound_ connectivity to the Internet while preventing _inbound_ access -- so it allows the resources in the Private Subnet to access the Internet but maintains their isolation in the private subnet.

Comment: Thanks John. Load Balancer is configured. Health Statsu ports are enabled. I have hosted default website on IIS on EC2 on port 80/443. Health Status ports are 80/443. Ports are added in security groups as well. However, health status returns unhealthy. Now, when I am calling https://myorg.int.com, I am expecting to view default website running on EC2 in IIS which wont happen.

Comment: The Health Check goes to the provided URL and expects a `200` response. If that isn't working, try connecting to a Bastion instance in the public subnet and `curl` the same URL as the Health Check to see what it is returning. (You might need to adjust Security Groups for this to work.)

Comment: Regarding load balancer to forward traffic request, looks like everything is correct as specified in the AWS documentation. However, I have observed that there are crowed strike agent and other security services running on EC2 that might be blocking something when I am calling website from public ip.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a secondary network interface to the instance. Put the primary ENI in the public subnet and the second ENI in the private subnet. Assign appropriate values in the respective security groups.